# A Lindenmayer system case

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals, lindenmayer

Obviously the optimal way to make something like this

[image]

is the Lindenmayer systems in TikZ.

Here are some attempts of mine, kept per suggestion in a comment.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{try}{
  \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=.6\pgflsystemstep}
  \rule{X -> FS[S-Y]YF}
  \rule{Y -> FS[SX-]XF}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate=45]
    [l-system={try, axiom=X, order=10, step=124pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{try}{
  \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=.8\pgflsystemstep}
  \rule{X -> FX[-SFY]FX}
  \rule{Y -> FY[+FX]FY}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate=-45]
    [l-system={try, axiom=X, order=7, step=1.2pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{try}{
  \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=.67\pgflsystemstep}
  \symbol{p}{\draw circle (.01\pgflsystemstep);}
  \rule{X -> FS[+S[p]Y]X}
  \rule{Y -> FS[S[p]X]Y}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate=135]
    [l-system={try, axiom=X, order=12, step=140pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{try}{
  \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=.67\pgflsystemstep}
  \symbol{p}{\draw circle (.01\pgflsystemstep);}
  \rule{X -> [p]FS[-ff++SY]X}
  \rule{Y -> [p]FS[+ff--SX]Y}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate=45]
    [l-system={try, axiom=X, order=12, step=160pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give the code of your experiments?

Comment: @AndréC OK although this is going to be disappointing...

Comment: If it wasn't, you wouldn't be asking for help here, would you?

Comment: @AndréC That's right. But I also think it is hardly helpful for those who would like to help.

Comment: Those who like to help, also like to learn by looking for what they have never thought about.

Comment: @AndréC Well here is another one then :)

Comment: where does this picture come from?

Comment: @BlackMild I made this with Mathematica, it is the Hasse diagram of a particular poset I need.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, you should answer normally in the answer part and not in the question as indicated here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AndréC Actually I managed to further improve it, so it is reasonably close now, will do

Comment: Your question got these 11 votes only when you showed your different tests. The people who voted, voted for these tests. Leave them visible in the question.

Comment: @AndréC I don't know how to revert the edits, and I did not keep all these intermediate versions of code. Besides, the final form of the question/answer matters more, does not it? I mean, for somebody who will see it for the first time, it is the question and final answer that would matter, not all the intermediate stuff.

Comment: No, the intermediate versions count just as much since they make it possible to understand the path of thought towards the solution. What is interesting is the reasoning that can find the solution, not the solution in itself, especially since it is not explained.

Comment: So all you have to do is put back what you have removed by a simple copy and paste.

Comment: @AndréC OK did it. Still not sure whether it is better this way

Comment: You see you just had two new votes. This is because by making your tests visible, users are interested in your problem. And if you explain the reasoning that allowed you to write this solution, you will get even more votes because users will understand the question as well as the answer.

Comment: @AndréC You are right, but this was basically trial and error, not much to explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a code coming reasonably close to it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{try}{
  \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=.67\pgflsystemstep}
  \symbol{p}{\draw circle (.01\pgflsystemstep);}
  \rule{X -> [p]S[-FF++SY]Xf}
  \rule{Y -> [p]S[+FF--SX]Yf}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate=45]
    [l-system={try, axiom=X, order=12, step=280pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Whether it can be made better, I don't know, everybody is invited to further improve it

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is not yet a complete answer but because of the OP's input we may be getting there. What this answer does is to define a rule for the zigzags of decreasing amplitude, and a way to combine them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\def\pgflsystemturnr{%
    \pgftransformrotate{-90}}%
\def\pgflsystemturnl{%
    \pgftransformrotate{90}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[l-system={step=10pt, order=7,angle=165}] 
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{pft}{
    \symbol{D}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=0.9\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{I}{\pgflsystemstep=1.1\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemstep=3\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{l}{\pgflsystemturnl}
    \symbol{r}{\pgflsystemturnr}
    \rule{Z -> [Y]-DDDDDSS+Z} % line up zigzag
    \rule{Y -> -DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI} % zigzag
  }
  \draw [red,rotate=-60] (0,0) l-system [l-system={pft, axiom=Z, anchor=south west}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using this one can get something that resembles your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\def\pgflsystemturnr{%
    \pgftransformrotate{-90}}%
\def\pgflsystemturnl{%
    \pgftransformrotate{90}}%
\newcounter{lmn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[l-system={step=10pt, order=8,angle=165},line join=bevel,
pics/linden row/.style={code={\draw[shorten >=-#1*0.05cm] (0,0) -- (-142.5:2*#1)
foreach \XX in {1,...,#1} {coordinate[pos={pow(0.75,\XX-1)}] (p-#1-\XX)
node[circle,fill,pos={1.02*pow(0.75,\XX-1)},scale={pow(0.75,\XX-1)}]{}};
\foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
{\draw[rotate=-57.5] (p-#1-\XX)
l-system [l-system={pft,step={pow(0.8,-#1+2*\XX+5)*4pt}, axiom=Z, anchor=west}];}}}] 
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{pft}{
    \symbol{D}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \symbol{S}{\pgflsystemstep=0.9\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{I}{\pgflsystemstep=1.1\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemstep=3\pgflsystemstep}
    \symbol{l}{\pgflsystemturnl}
    \symbol{r}{\pgflsystemturnr}
    \symbol{o}{\stepcounter{lmn}%
    \pgfnode{coordinate}{center}{\pgfpointorigin}{X\number\value{lmn}}{}}%
    \symbol{c}{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{X\number\value{lmn}}{center}}}
    \rule{Z -> [Y]-DDDDDSS+Z} % line up zigzag
    \rule{Y -> rMl-Do[rD]I+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI+DI-DI[c]+DI} % zigzag
  }
  \path foreach \X in {4,5,...,8} {(-30:{pow(1.2,\X)*6cm}) pic{linden row=\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The obvious way to fix it would be to use `[...]` but this causes `dimension too large` errors.

Comment: Does not decreasing step help with "dimension too large"?

Comment: No, - I cannot figure out where to put the `[...]`. As for the size - it is OK as long as enough detail is visible

Comment: (note that in my second attempt step is quite small)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You were absolutely right, it does help!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Now there is *something* that vaguely resembles your screen shot. The outer repetition is done in an explicit loop, the main reason being that I do not know if it is possible to have a Lindenmayer system repeat something n times, where n varies.